# Regexp word boundary for substrings matches even if it should not

Tags: regex

I've this string `asdas d HC-HMC BACK SIDE saas` and these regexp:

```
\bHC\b

\bHC-HMC BACK SIDE\b
```

I expect the first regular expression fails while the second should match. Trying it I see that both match but I don't understand why.

This is the first regexp: https://regex101.com/r/hBZK2h/1

And this is the second one: https://regex101.com/r/TEZmP6/1

I have to create a regular expression that matches exactly the string with boundary `HC-HMC BACK SIDE` but **not** the string `HC`. Any hint?

Comment: You need to understand what a [word boundary (`\b`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\bHC\b` pattern matches `HC` if it is at the start of the string or is preceded with a non-word char (not a letter, a digit, and `_` (and maybe other chars depending on the regex Unicode support) and that is at the end of string or immediately followed with a non-word char. See [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) definition.

You may add a `(?!-)` lookahead to the first regex to make it fail if `HC` is followed with `-`:

```
\bHC\b(?!-)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hBZK2h/2)